# Creating a constraint check in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of questions that can be put into a random order by the system but at the same time there are checks for certain questions that need to come before a different question ex.

`q1 before q4, q3 before q2`

I have to also make sure that there isn't something like this in there though:

`q1 before q4, q3 before q2, q2 before q1, q4 before q2`

I'm not entirely sure how this is going to be done.

A way of storing this I was given as an example would be a number array of arrays `let n: number[number, number][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're lazy, which I am, since there are only a few questions, I would just randomly order the questions and check against the rules, if it violates them just run it again.

If this is a homework assignment and you'll be marked down for being lazy, you can create a function which randomly assigns questions to slots in an array, starting with questions which must come after the others, then reduce the range of the random number generator for the ones which must be less to have a maximum of the randomly generated position the one which must be greater than appears in.

For example:

lets say you have an array of questions of length 5. and q1 has to appear before q3 and q4 has to appear before q2. First place q3 in a random position in an array of length 5, lets say that poition is 2. Then randomly assign q1 to a position less than 2. Do that for each set of rules, each time a number is assigned remove it from the RNG, once all the rules are completed run the other questions.

You can represent a constraint as a tuple with the first string representing the question which must come first and the second as the question which must come second. `rules: number[][] = [['q1', 'q3], ['q4', 'q2']]` would be your rules and you would have all questions in a question array `questions: string[] = ['q1', 'q2', ...]` each time a question is assigned from the tuples remove it from the questions array using splice getting the index of the string. Heres some code which should work with those two data types, notice I use an array of available indices to exclude previously chosen indices:

```
questions: string[]; // put all questions here.
rules: string[][]; // put all less than rules as tuples here, 
// i.e. q1 must come before q2 written as [['q1', 'q2'],...]

randomizer(): string[] {
  const arr = new Array<string>(this.questions.length);
  const availableIndices = [];
  let rand: number;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    availableIndices.push(i)
  }
  for (const tuple of rules) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableIndices.length)
    arr[availableIndices[rand]] = tuple[1];
    questions.splice(indexOf(tuple[1]), 1);
    availableIndices.splice(indexOf(rand), 1);
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableIndices.indexOf(tuple[1]))
    arr[availableIndices[rand]] = tuple[0];
    questions.splice(indexOf(tuple[2]), 1);
    availableIndices.splice(indexOf(rand), 1);
  }
  for (const q of questions) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableIndices.length);
    arr[availableIndices[rand]] = q;
    availableIndices.splice(indexOf(rand), 1);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

This algorithm is O(n) so your teacher can't complain.

Comment: This could work but I used the number of questions as an example the number of questions is never guaranteed

Comment: Yes see my edit, I'll keep going adding some more details for you.

Comment: @amedeiros see my edit, I did this outside an ide so didn't really error check it but it should work with minimum modification and will work with any number of questions and rules just put questions into questions array and rules into the tuple i described.

Comment: It will need to be changed a little just little things but its a great example none the less even if it helps to get going in the right direction